# How to display all ways to give change

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

As far as I know, counting every way to give change to a set sum and a starting till configuration is a classic Dynamic Programming problem.

I was wondering if there was a way to *also* display (or store) the actual change structures that could possibly amount to the given sum while preserving the DP complexity.

I have never saw this issue being discussed and I would like some pointers or a brief explanation of how this can be done or why this cannot be done.

Comment: You could just store answers in an array and print them when you've finished solving..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DP for change problem has time complexity O(Sum * ValuesCount) and storage complexity O(Sum).
You can prepare extra data for this problem in the same time as DP for change, but you need more storage O(O(Sum*ValuesCount), and a lot of time for output of all variants O(ChangeWaysCount).

To prepare data for way recovery, make the second array B of arrays (or lists). When you incrementing count array A element from some previous element, add used value to corresponding element of B. At the end, unwind all the ways from the last element.
Example: values 1,2,3, sum 4

```
index    0         1          2          3         4
A        0         1          2          3         4
B        -         1          1 2        1 2 3     1 2 3
```

We start unwinding from B[4] elements:

```
1-1-1-1 (B[4]-B[3]-B[2]-B[1])
2-1-1   (B[4]-B[2]-B[1])
2-2     (B[4]-B[2])
3-1     (B[4]-B[1])
```

Note that I have used only ways with non-increasing values to avoid permutation variants (i.e. 1-3 and 3-1)

Comment: So retrieving all the variants from the DP setup has the same time complexity as the naive method of calculating the ways of making change?

Comment: If naive method means generation all variants - yes.